# In famo.us, what is the best approach to sizing text elements on surfaces?

Tags: javascript, css, famo.us

Question is quite simple, say I have a surface that's taking up 0.8% width, and 0.1% height, and I want my text to fill that appropriately, how do I size it? I currently have the text size property set like so:

```
      {fontSize: window.innerHeight * 0.06}
```

But if the text is long and takes up more space than the surface, it runs over. So, how do make a responsive text size for the surface?

Answer (score 0):

in the case where it runs over, what behaviour would you want? a new line?
you can still use normal responsive layout CSS and insert a DIV inside a famous surface.